# I need help on writing a program in vvm that can divide two numbers

Tags: assembly, vvm

i really need some help with this, im trying to write a program in vvm assembly language which will divide two number for example divide number A by number B

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Since [vvm](http://www.cba.uri.edu/vvm/coding.html) doesn't have a divide instruction in hardware, you're going to have to do it "manually".  It doesn't even have right-shift or any boolean ops that would let you test the last bit.

However, adding a number to itself is a left-shift, so you can probably still make an algorithm that runs in log(n) time, rather than just repeated subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for that really small machine is to repeatedly subtract the divisor from the dividend until the result becomes negative:

This example performs 12/4:

```
lda 90
brz 20
sub 91
sto 90
brp 10
jmp 20
*10
lda 92
add 93
sto 92
jmp 00
*20
lda 92
out
hlt
*90
dat 012
dat 004
dat 000
dat 001
```

Comment: It's actually un-helpful to students to hand them a solution.  I know this doesn't solve the general problem, but I think it's better to stick to English descriptions of things.  A broad question gets a broad answer from me, rather than any code for a specific solution.  [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).  I answered, but also voted to close as too-broad, and downvoted for not showing an attempt. :/